# Текст поверх картинки в email письме

Tags: email-layout, вёрстка, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать текст поверх картинки в email письме.
Верстаю письмо таблицами, и пытался внутри таблицы создать div с текстом и наложить поверх картинки, но в приходящих письмах (gmail) все позиции пропадают (удаляются), т.е. отображается просто дивы один за другим:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="position: relative;">
        <img src="/images/content-image.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div style="position: absolute;">
        Мой текст
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вот так делаю:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td style="background-image: url(http://name.ru/images/content-image.jpg)">
        Мой текст
    </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

А дальше ровняю паддингами на td.

Нормально работает во всех мейл-системах, насколько я знаю.

Comment: Конечно, хотелось бы так сделать, но большинство email клиентов не поддерживает `background-image`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635803/table-background-image-in-email

Comment: Первый раз такое слышу.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Как раз большинство поддерживает. Тогда - через background просто.
А вообще - можно открыть любое письмо-рассылку, и там видно, что все используют background-image =)

Comment: Можно конечно использовать VML for Outlook 2007/2010/2013, and HTML/CSS for Outlook 2000/2003, Gmail, Hotmail и т.п. ищу простой вариант но если нет простого будет через VML ;-)

Comment: Спасибо за таблицу, проверю под разными клиентами! спс!